# Tell me what's wrong with this code GOLANG

Tags: go, math, printing

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {

    distencecalc()
}

func distencecalc() {

    fmt.Println("X1 :")
    var x1 float64
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &x1)
    fmt.Print("")
    fmt.Println("Y1 :")
    var y1 float64
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &y1)
    fmt.Print("")
    fmt.Println("Z1 :")
    var z1 float64
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &z1)
    fmt.Print("")
    fmt.Println("X2 :")
    var x2 float64
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &x2)
    fmt.Print("")
    fmt.Println("Y2 :")
    var y2 float64
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &y2)
    fmt.Print("")

    fmt.Println("Z2 :")
    var z2 float64
    fmt.Scanf("%f", &z2)
    fmt.Print("")

    var Xcalc = x2 - x1
    var Ycalc = y2 - y1
    var Zcalc = z2 - z1



    var calcX = math.Pow(Xcalc, 2)
    var calcY = math.Pow(Ycalc, 2)
    var calcZ = math.Pow(Zcalc, 2)


    var allcalc = calcX + calcZ + calcY
    fmt.Println("the result is :")
    fmt.Println(math.Sqrt(allcalc))
}
```

The problem is I compile then run the program it asks about x1 I enter the value and it asks about y1 and z1 at the same time.

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by Scanf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code in question works on unix systems, but usually the problem is that calls like `fmt.Scanf("%f", &x1)` does not consume newlines, but quoting from package doc of [`fmt: Scanning`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning):

> Scan, Fscan, Sscan treat newlines in the input as spaces.

And on Windows the newline is not a single `\n` character but `\r\n`, so the subsequent `fmt.Scanf()` call will proceed immediately without waiting for further input from the user.

So you have to add a newline to your format string to avoid subsequent `fmt.Scanf()` call to proceed:

```
fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &x1)
```

But easier would be to just use [`fmt.Scanln()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) and skip the whole format string:

```
fmt.Scanln(&x1)
```

> Scanln, Fscanln and Sscanln stop scanning at a newline and require that the items be followed by a newline or EOF.

The scanner functions (`fmt.ScanXXX()`) return you the number of successfully scanned items and an `error`. To tell if scanning succeeded, you have to check its return value, e.g.:

```
if _, err := fmt.Scanln(&x1); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Scanning failed:", err)
}
```