# fmt.Scanf does not consume all the characters through the end of the string

Tags: go, scanf

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
    var i int
    fmt.Print("input integer: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)

}
```

when I run this small program from terminal and give input as

```
input integer: 3.ls
```

it also executes `ls` command
or when i give input

```
input integer: 665.cd someDir
```

it executes `cd someDir`.
Is this normal behavior with Scanf in go.This does not happen in C.
Can someone explain what's happening.

Comment: No, it's not a bug in the standard library. It's never a bug in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)` call only parses an integer from the input, it **does not** consume input until the end of line.

If you input `3.ls`, then `3` is parsed as the decimal number, and `.` is consumed and will stop the scanning. Your app ends here, so the rest (`ls` and the newline) will be executed by your shell.

Use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) to read *lines*, e.g.:

```
fmt.Print("input string: ")
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
if !scanner.Scan() {
    return // no input
}
var i int
fmt.Sscanf(scanner.Text(), "%d", &i)
fmt.Println("Entered:", i)
```

See related: [Tell me what's wrong with this code GOLANG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761166/tell-me-whats-wrong-with-this-code-golang/54761389#54761389)

Comment: Wanted to add a comment expanding on that buffering thing but that ended up being too large for a comment. If you find that info relevant, please feel free to include it into your answer and I'll delete mine ;-)

Comment: @kostix I think it's fine as your separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just an expansion on what @icza wrote but too big to fit into a comment.

I'd also try to shed more light at why that

> does not happen in C

effect takes place.

Most probably you have used [`scanf(3)`](https://manpages.debian.org/3/scanf), and the functions of its ilk operate *not* on file descriptors (like syscall wrappers such as [`read(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/read) and [`write(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/write)) but rather on so-called "streams" provided by the C standard library; these facilities are referred to as ["stdio"](https://manpages.debian.org/3/stdio).

These streams provide default buffering and `stdin` is usually line-buffered by default.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rc, i;

    printf("input integer: ");

    rc = scanf("%d", &i);
    if (rc != 1) {
        perror("scan failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If we build it

```
$ gcc -o scanf -W -Wall -Werror scanf.c
```

and then run "as is", we observe that the program have consumed those extra `.ls` characters:

```
$ ./scanf
input integer: 3.ls
$
```

Let's now see what happens when we modify the idea of the buffering to use by default of the `libc` linked to our program. We'll use [`stdbuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/1/stdbuf) for that:

```
$ stdbuf -i 0 ./scanf
input integer: 3.ls
scanf scanf.c
$
```

That's why the @icza's advice works: in Go, variables form the `os` package which hold the file objects opened to the standard streams have no buffering as they are of type `*os.File`, and those are quite thin wrappers around the file descriptors returned by the OS.

If you need buffering you should explicitly use it where it belongs (and be careful about it: do not mix reads/writes on a buffering wrapper and its underlying data source/sink—at least unless you're absolutely sure what you're doing).